# Как получить данные из SQLite  в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, не могу получить значения из базы SQLite

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

...
DataTable datatabl = new DataTable();

```
    public void Zanesti_dannie_v_tablicy()
    {

                    SQLiteConnection connection =
                new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};", databaseName));
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM test ";
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCommand, connection);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
            datatabl.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Оёёй!");
        }
    }
-------------------------------
Студия выдала вообще какой-то бред "Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime".  строка(  datatabl.Load(reader);  )Хотя я взял это из примера для MSSql где это работало.
```

При чём тут DateTime..
    Подскажите пожалуйста, как прочитать из базы и занести в таблицу.
    Спасибо

Comment: омайгадбл!
ужасное имя метода Zanesti_dannie_v_tablicy()

Comment: так же не советую все оборачивать в один Try-Catch блок.

Comment: Да, лучше уж тогда по русски назвать метод.

Comment: А в datatabl есть колонки DateTime?

Comment: Аааа...ЧАД ты гений. Да. В таблице есть, а я вообще не понял-в чём дело. Только теперь тогда второй вопрос, а что с этим делать?Спасибо

Comment: Если вместо звёздочки в запросе ставлю поля (не datetime) -всё работает, а с датой чёто ругается...

Comment: Есть такая беда - у SQLite нет формата даты.

Comment: У него есть, дело в том, что я взял эту базу с проги под андройд и хочу с ней на компе работать, а с этими базами до этого не работал

Comment: Нету в спецификации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что у SQLite нет формата колонки дата. Тут либо беда в данных (не может распарсить).

Либо явно указывать колонку. Это вроде лечит. Если вспомню красивое решение этой проблемы (было пару лет назад) - напишу.

Попробуйте в запросе колонку с датой обернуть во что то, что воспримется как дата гридом. Беда явно в том что null читается адаптером как "", а это не может сконвертиться в DateTime

Comment: Спасибо, вообщем, по непонятным мне причинам-заработало. Я скопировал всё по новой в проект под .Net4 (а до этого был .net4.5).
Спасибо. Сори, что запудрил мозги.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример [тут](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.html)

Comment: А у Devart-а получается это своя библиотека доступа к базам? она чем-то отличается от обычной?